# Select a postgres database after onnect on java

Tags: java, postgresql

This code connects abd create a database ,how can I select the created database to use it?

```
public class Connect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/","postgres", "12345");


            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute("CREATE DATABASE mydb");
            //now I hav to connect to mydb

            connection.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OracleToPostgres.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OracleToPostgres.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: have you considered creating another connection with your new database?

Comment: Why don't you simply close the connection and open another one with the correct db?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do ...

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb", "user", "password");
```